# Representing arbitrary implementations of a typeclass in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to overcome years of working within the classic Java-style inheritance model to truly get comfortable with Haskell. It hasn't been going well, and I need a bit of help.

Suppose I have a typeclass `Foo`. I want to represent a list of arbitrary implementing classes of `Foo`, but not in a way that restricts every item in the list to be the same; I need to have a heterogeneous, open type so consumers of my library can implement their own `Foo`.

The reason why is because I'd like to write something like the following (pidgin Haskell):

```
class Foo -- something...

data Bar = Bar Int Char
data Baz = Baz String

instance Foo Bar
instance Foo Baz

saySomething :: Foo -> String
saySomething (Bar x _) = "Bar number " ++ (show x)
saySomething (Baz x) = "Your baz is " ++ x
saySomething _ = "Unknown Foo"

sayAll :: [Foo] -> [String]
sayAll = map (saySomething)

main = putStrLn $ sayAll [ (Bar 5 'k'), (Bar 7 'G'), (Baz "hello") ]
```

**How would I create an extensible typeclass (or other datatype) that can be freely mixed with others of the same typeclass, but not necessarily the same exact type?**

Comment: What do you mean by extensible typeclass? Typeclasses define a [set of functions that can have different implementations depending on the type of data they're given](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html). For example `class Eq a where (==), (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool` means that instance types of `Eq` will have to implement `(==)` and `(/=)`. It's for ensuring that they will have these operations. I didn't get what you mean by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking is [Heterogenous collections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections)

IMHO the best way is to use existentials, as described on wiki:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Showable = forall a . Show a => MkShowable a

pack :: Show a => a -> Showable
pack = MkShowable

hlist :: [Showable]
hlist = [ pack 3
        , pack 'x'
        , pack pi
        , pack "string"
        , pack (Just ()) ]
```

Comment: This is an [antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) -- there's no practical difference between a `[Showable]` and a `[String]`, and the latter is much simpler.

Comment: You're right, but what if the typeclass provides more than one method?

Comment: Actually, my opinion is not as radical as the one expressed by Luke Palmer in his blog, but I do think he has a point. The existential-typeclass pattern can be useful in some cases, but it can be easily abused.

Comment: There will be more than one method on `Foo`. Thank you @utdemir for the answer, and @chi for the link to Luke Palmer's article, as I may rewrite my code once I wrap my head around the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with what you are trying to do (heterogenous) collection is that : once you have a list of `Foo` it's hard to go back to the original type. However, if you are happy to *forget* the original type, an other way to solve your problem is to *convert* your data to `Foo`. This approach might seems wrong but remember, data are immutable in Haskell, so you'll never be able to modify your objects anyway, so the only thing you can do with your `Foo`s is get information from them. There is then no difference between a real `Bar` acting like a `Foo` and a new `Foo` acting as the `Bar` version would (also, Haskell lazy, so the *conversion* will be only done if needed).

When you realized that, you can even go further and replace `object` but just a bunch of functions (as stated in @chi link). Your code becomes

```
 data Foo = { saySomething :: String, saySomethingElse :: String }
 -- Haskell is lazzy, so saySomething can be seen as function
 -- without argument

 class Fooable a where
       toFoo :: a -> Foo

 data Bar = Bar Int Char
 data Baz = Bar String

 instance Fooable Bar where
        toFoo (Bar i c) = { "Bar number : " ++ show i, "Bar char : " ++ [c] }
 instance Fooable Baz where
        toFoo (Baz s) = {"Your baz is " ++ s, "Nothing to add." }

 sayAll : [Foo] -> [String]
 sayAll = map saySomething

 bar = Bar 1 'a'
 baz = Baz "Bazzar"

 sayAll [toFoo bar, toFoo baz]
```

Please note, that even though `somethingElse` doesn't look like a function but it's just a plain function, it will never been called (in this example). The result of `toFoo` can be seen as a *bridge* between `Bar` and `Foo`.